# Unable to find element in a webview using onWebView method in Espresso

Tags: android, webview, android-espresso

I am using the following dependency for writing my espresso tests:

```
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-intents:3.0.2'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-contrib:3.0.2'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-web:3.0.2'
```

I am trying to detect if the webview has loaded successfully using the following code:

```
onWebView().withElement(findElement(Locator.XPATH, "//h1[contains(text(),'Login')]"));
```

This was working until I extend the support of my app to OREO (API 27). 
After upgrading the target version I have update my espresso dependency from 2.2 to 3.0.2. After upgrade, `onWebview` method always return a webview with no elements in it even when I can see the webview being loaded in the Android device.

I would like to test, if the webview has loaded in the device.

Any help is appreciated! 
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

It was a dump mistake from my side.. !!

I am answering this for someone who is stuck like this in future..

I have added a new transition in one of the view and for that I have disabled hardware acceleration which . Please make sure Hardware acceleration is enabled in your manifest file.
Remove the following line, if you find it in your manifest before running your tests.

```
android:hardwareAccelerated="false"
```

This hardware acceleration is also configurableat three different levels (application, activity, view). Please refer [this](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/hardware-accel) link.